# Printing data with give start and end

Tags: c, arrays

Help on how to print all with in a given start and end

first this is the function in main

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", Codes[i]);
    OneStock_ManyDailyData( DS, DS[i].Nametag, "10/2/2017", "11/6/2017" );        
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

this calls the function

```
void OneStock_ManyDailyData(struct company DS[30], Symbol code, StrDate start, StrDate end) {
    int i;
    int c;
    int x;
    int y;
    int a;

    for(i=0; i<30; i++) {
        //printf("Entered Loop\n");

        if(strcmp(DS[i].Nametag, code) == 0) {
            //printf("Gotcha!\n");

            for(c=0; c<DS[i].ndd; c++){
                //printf("Entered Second Loop\n");

            }
        }
    getch();
}
```

what codes should in put inside the 2nd for loop in order to get the range of start and end

this last part is displays can be inserted inside the for loop but it only display 1 start or given date

```
if(strcmp(DS[i].Values[c].date, date)==0){
    printf("%s \t%.2f \t%.2f \t%.2f \t%.2f \t%.0f\n", DS[i].Values[c].date, DS[i].Values[c].open, DS[i].Values[c].high, DS[i].Values[c].low, DS[i].Values[c].close, DS[i].Values[c].volume);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You can't pass an array as a parameter in c.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to work on functions in C.To study and follow some tutorials.
Here you write:

```
void OneStock_ManyDailyData(struct company DS[30], Symbol code, StrDate start, StrDate end)
```

First of all you can't pass an array as a parameter in C.You have to pass a pointer of the start of the array.So

```
void OneStock_ManyDailyData(struct company* ds, Symbol code, StrDate start, StrDate end)
```

What we do here is to pass a pointer for the first element of the array (this is what we do in C)
Now you need to iterate the ds[30].To do this we need to say to the function also the number of elements , so where the iteration knows where to stop.
We also need to know how big is the step of iteration , in this case and usually we can find it by `sizeof(our_element)`.

Iteration goes like this:

```
void iterate_ds(struct company* ds , int elements , ... , ...)
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 , i < 30 , i ++)
    {
        do_what_you_want(ds[i]);
    }
}
```

You don't provide me the structure of your struct so I can't say what you have in `do_what_you_want(ds[i]);` .However I think you could have another iteration alongside with checking , or whatever , by passing the parameters like we did for ds array.
I hope this helps  :)

PS:Pointers is what we pass in functions in C and pointer is just an integer that holds the address where the element we created lies to.